# Can I delete from a table currently being read without a lock issue

Tags: mysql

I have a process which deletes 30 days worth of data from a table every day & replaces it with the newer data.

Sometimes, someone will be running a query when this deletion begins, which causes the delete to fail because the table is locked for read.

Is there a way around this? I don't care if the read shows some data that was subsequently deleted - the more important process is the delete

Thanks

Comment: Table engine is?

Comment: Hope you're using InnoDB!

Comment: Tip: Create a new table, repopulate it, then do a quick `RENAME TABLE a TO _a, new_a TO a` to swap them. If this fails, try again.

Comment: Thanks guys - it is INNODB. I can;t do the rename, it holds 3 years worth of data but the last 30 days is liable to change, so I reinsert as it was much faster than trying to update records!